# convert pdf to images using php

Tags: php, image-processing, imagick

i am trying to get images of a pdf file. but the problem is that my code produce error for some pdf files. probably file size problem

this is my code

```
$saved_file_location = "images.pdf";
$destination_dir = "t";
$Name = "123";

exec('convert -verbose -density 150 '.$saved_file_location.' -crop 1020x490+128+40 -quality 90 '.$destination_dir."/".$Name.'-%03d.jpg');
sleep(5);
//echo filesize($destination_dir."/".$Name.'-000.jpg'). "<br>";
if(filesize($destination_dir."/".$Name.'-000.jpg') < 10000)
{
    exec('convert -verbose -density 150 '.$saved_file_location.' -crop 1020x490+128+580 -quality 90 '.$destination_dir."/".$Name.'-%03d.jpg');
    sleep(5);
    //echo filesize($destination_dir."/".$Name.'-001.jpg')."<br>";
    if(filesize($destination_dir."/".$Name.'-001.jpg') < 10000)
    {
        exec('convert -verbose -density 150 '.$saved_file_location.' -crop 1020x490+128+1125 -quality 90 '.$destination_dir."/".$Name.'-%03d.jpg');
    }
}
```

and this error i get

```
PHP Warning:  filesize(): stat failed for t/123-000.jpg in /home3/domain/pdf_to_images.php on line 10
```

some time the code work fine and produce multiple images of pdf file but some time i get this error

Comment: No one is going to be able to help you. For some reason filesize is failing on your system, but only you can investigate what the cause of that is.

Comment: any suggestion how i can track this problem

Comment: Do `filesize("ThisFileDoesntExist.txt");` - it gives the same error message. Either the file you're trying to read the size of doesn't exist or you don't have access to it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all ImageMagick `convert` command internally uses ghostscript's `gs` command and `gs` is faster comparing to `convert` so it is always good to use ghostscript if you are not using ImageMagick specific features. and the other thing is rather than constructing the command by yourself I would recommend using library already written and tested to avoid waste of time trying to understand all the combinations of a commands.

you will find good libraries [packagist.org](https://packagist.org/search/?q=pdf%20to%20image)

here a library I wrote which will be useful [PdfLib](https://github.com/imalhasaranga/PDFLib) who reads your question in the future

```
$pdflib = new ImalH\PDFLib\PDFLib();
$pdflib->setPdfPath($pdf_file_path);
$pdflib->setOutputPath($folder_path_for_images);
$pdflib->setImageFormat(\ImalH\PDFLib\PDFLib::$IMAGE_FORMAT_PNG);
$pdflib->setDPI(300);
$pdflib->setPageRange(1,$pdflib->getNumberOfPages());
$pdflib->convert();
```